# subquery in update fails MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I already tried looking at some threads but i can't hardly make my QUERY work.

here is the error message

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'tblUser' for update in FROM clause


UPDATE tblUser 
SET logId = (
    SELECT CONCAT((
        SELECT logId FROM tblUser 
        WHERE resultId = '2014-02-11 21:31:35'),'45') 
    from tblUser)  
WHERE rulesId = '14'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read and write to the same table if you're using a transactional storage engine. The reason is simple, the table is locked for writing from your `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: Okay sir thank you ill just try it the other way, actually in conjunction with MYSQL im using VB.net so i will just do a separate select query first then do the UPDATE query (this maybe off topic but just want you to know), more power thanks again.